# Google App Engine, Secure Data Connector (SDC), and supported protocols

Tags: google-app-engine, integration, network-protocols

I've been investigating what I can do with Google's Secure Data Connector and App Engine.

Is it possible, from an App Engine application, to grab resources inside my corporate intranet without using HTTP(S)?

From what I read in the documentation, the only way to request resources through SDC is by using url_fetch, which is limited to HTTP, right?

Comment: I think the title has a minor typo - Secure Data Connector should be abbreviated "SDC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that app engine does not let you to other hosts or use sockets directly except through its URLFetch API which is [limited to HTTP](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox).  However, you are not stuck to traditional ports - you can use it to access ports 80-90, 440-450, and 1024-65535 (as of [GAE v1.3.2](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes)).

It doesn't seem like this restriction should matter much if you are planning on using SDC - the [SDC FAQ](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/faq.html) seems to indicate that it uses HTTP/HTTPS to connect to resources on your intranet anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was wondering if I could access other resources which are not served through HTTP, such as directly connecting to an internal database (I know, kind of lazy approach!!). I guess the restriction may actually lead me to follow better practices and write a Web Service for internal data access.